# Why IOC is outdated according to MSDN?

Tags: inversion-of-control, msdn

It is said here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921087.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IoC/ Dependency Injection is not outdated at all in my opinion. Its actually becoming more and more popular as more frameworks are being introduced for it. If its not solething you are currently looking to use then I would suggest having a look into it

try out ninject or structuremap if you havent already.

I have only recently got into it and its something i now feel very strongly about

Comment: Thanks will look at ninject and structuremap

Answer (score 11):

I believe it's the Composite Application Library material that's retired, and not the concept of IoC in general.

Comment: Yes, every page in that section has the same disclaimer.